# setting the hight of items in the wookmark JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an issue when rendering the layout of tiles using the Wookmark JQuery plugin. This is primarily because the content of each item is combination of images and text (or in some cases just text) and as such the internal height is unknown.

I had thought I'd cracked the problem by setting the height of the `<li class="nItem">` by updating the `applyLayout()` function:

```
function applyLayout() {
  if(handler) handler.wookmarkClear();

  //set the height of the li
  $('#tiles li').each(function(){$(this).height($(this).height())})

  options = {
    autoResize: true,
    container: $('#gridMain'),
    offset: 10,
    itemWidth: 222
  };
  handler = $('#tiles li');
  handler.wookmark(options);
};
```

Unfortunately sometimes, some item content still bleeds out into the next item below it.

Is there a way to handle dynamic content within tiles? or has anyone got any suggestions on a fix?

Many thanks

@JustinReid

Comment: I have also tried setting the height if the item content by introducing a container div `.itemContent` and setting using `$('#tiles li').each(function(){$(this).find('.itemContent').height($(this).height()-7)})` - unfortunately I still get the issue. Much appreciated if anyone has any suggestions?